# How come when I play rendered animations all of my old animations play too?

Tags: rendering, animation

Okay so I'm in a new project and I've animated a heartbeat, when I go to play that animation I see it, then after that all my other animations from old projects start player after it in the same window, why is this happening?

I cannot find an answer anywhere, it's really annoying!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that all your animations are frame sequence renders and that they have the same name and live in the same render folder? Blender will play any frame sequence that has a consistent sequence of numbers in the same folder.

To fix this behavior try creating new folders for each rendered sequence or at least different names each time you render.